# Is there a way to have smooth/subpixel motion without turning on smoothing on graphics?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm creating this 2D, pixel art game. When the camera follows the player (it uses easing), on the final approach, the position gets several subpixel adjustments.

If I have smoothing ON (on my graphic assets), the graphics look good (sharp. it's pixel art) but the subpixel motion is jerky/jumpy.

If I have smoothing OFF, the subpixel motion is smooth, but the pixel art graphics look blurry.

I'm using Flash player v21. I've tried this with Starling and with Flash's display list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pixelated object that is moving in increments of less than the pixel size, but you don't want to restrict your mathematical easing to integers, or even worse, factors of 8 or what have you.  The solution I am using in my project for this exact issue is posted below (I just got it working last week!)

### Concept

create a driver that is controlled by the easing using floating point numbers.
Allow this driver to then control where the actual display object is rendered.  We can use a constraint to only allow the display object to render on your chosen resolution.

### Code Example

```
// you'll put these lines or equivalent in the correct spots for your particular needs.
// SCALE_UP will be your resolution control.  If your pixels are 4 pixels wide, use 4.
const SCALE_UP: int = 4;
var d:CharacterDriver = new CharacterDriver();
var c:Character = new Character();
c._driver = d; // I've found it useful to be able to reference the driver
d._drives = c; // or the thing the driver drives via the linked object. 
               // you don't have to do this.
```

then when you are ready to do your easing of the driver:

```
function yourEase(c:Character, d:CharacterDriver):void{
    c.x = Math.ceil(d.x - Math.ceil(d.x)%SCALE_UP);//this converts a floating point number into a factor of SCALE_UP
    c.y = Math.ceil(d.y - Math.ceil(d.y)%SCALE_UP);
```

Now this will make your character move around 4 pixels at a time, but still be able to experience easing!

The bit with the modulo (%) operator is the key.  For instance,  102-102%4 = 100. 103-103%4 = 100. 104-104%4 = 104.

In case anyone is confused by that, look at what 102%4 does: 4 goes into 102 25 times with a remainder of 2.  so 102%4 = 2.  Then 102 - 2 = 100.

In your case, since the "camera" is following the player (i.e. the background is moving, right?) then you really need to apply drivers to everything in the background instead, but it is basically the same idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neal. My pixels are currently 1 pixel in size (instead of 4).
I'm currently moving the camera only if the speed is greater than 0.5 pixels per frame, which helps a bit.  
I also introduced some brownian motion (random/handycam motion) to the camera which showed me I'm really gonna depend on that smoothing for subpixel motion.

Comment: So when you say pixel art you just mean they are bitmaps, not that popular retro pixelated look.

Comment: And you want the motion to be smooth and the graphics to be sharp (meaning smooth unblurred edges). Let me know if I've got it right yet.

Comment: Yes, they are bitmaps with the retro pixelated look (like in the game Fez).  
I think you're saying that that style requires each color dot in the image to be 4 pixels in size. Is that correct?
I created my graphics with color dots of 1px in size, then I double the scale of the world. Oh.... I get it now.. haha.  
I had no idea it was done that way to avoid scaling the world.
And yes, I'd like the motion to be smooth and the graphics to be sharp (no bluring or anti-aliasing).

Comment: Ok so my method should work :) it worked for me and fez was my inspiration although I don't know what method he used. I literally just figured this method out a week ago!

Answer (score 0):

since you specifically mentioned the "final approach" i think your problem comes from the fact that the easing equations puts your graphics at fractional coordinates, especially while getting closer to the target, but you should also notice it during the rest of the animation.

depending on the easing "engine" that you're using you should be able to set a "round values" flag, so all the coordinates set will be integer values and not fractional
if that's not possible, find a way in your display objects to round the x and y values every time they change